# How the flush method in spring-data-jpa works?

Tags: java, spring-boot, transactions, spring-data, flush

I have sample project using `spring-boot-2.0.3` with `spring-data-jpa-2.0.3` and `postgresql-9.5.13`. It has only three classes: `@Entity`, `@Repository` and main class. DB has only one table with two fields: `id` and `name`.

I'm trying to `INSERT` `100 000` records in the loop into the table and measure execution time - enabling or disabling `flush()` method from `EntityManager` class for each 100 records.

Expected result is that execution time with enabled `flush()` method is much less then with disabled one, but actually I have the opposite result.

---

**Question:** What am I doing wrong?

---

**Project structure:**

[image: project structure]

---

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/twofold
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
```

---

**User.java**

```java
package twofold.data;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users", schema = "public")
public class User {

    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public User() {}

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "users_id_seq", sequenceName = "users_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "users_id_seq")
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "id: " + id + "; name: " + name + ";";
    }
}
```

---

**UserRepository.java**

```java
package twofold.data;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

---

**Application.java**

```java
package twofold;

import twofold.data.User;
import twofold.data.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner addUsers() {
        return new CommandLineRunner() {
            @Transactional
            public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
                long incoming = System.currentTimeMillis();
                for (int i = 1; i <= 100000; i++) {
                    userRepository.save(new User(i + "_name"));
                    if (i % 100 == 0) {
                        entityManager.flush();
                        entityManager.clear();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis()-incoming));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set following hibernate properties.

```xml
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="25" />
<property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.order_updates" value="true" />
```

Then do like this:

```java
int entityCount = 50;
int batchSize = 25;

EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
EntityTransaction entityTransaction = entityManager.getTransaction();

try {
    entityTransaction.begin();
    for (int i = 0; i < entityCount; i++) {
        if (i > 0 && i % batchSize == 0) {
            entityTransaction.commit();
            entityTransaction.begin();

            entityManager.clear();
        }
        Post post = new Post(
                String.format("Post %d", i + 1)
        );
        entityManager.persist(post);
    }
    entityTransaction.commit();
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
    if (entityTransaction.isActive()) {
        entityTransaction.rollback();
    }
    throw e;
} finally {
    entityManager.close();
}
```